# Check the foreground color of an NSAttributed string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSAttributedString` set in my `UITextView` and i need to check its `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` value.

```
char = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: attributedRange)
```

I tried to use this filter but i really don't know how to use it.

```
let attr = char.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
attr.filter({ (<#(key: NSAttributedStringKey, value: Any)#>) -> Bool in
            //if true...
        })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier to use the `attribute` method instead of `attributes`:

```
char = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: attributedRange)
if let color = char.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor {
    // color is the foreground color at location 0
} else {
    // there is no foreground color at location 0
}
```

Comment: That's true...Thanks :))))